# node.js discord.js В чем проблема?

Tags: javascript

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined. Код:

```
const banwords = [
  "гитлер",
  "фашизм",
  "hitler",
  "poop",
  "discord.gg",
  "http"
]
    bot.on("message", message => {
      let channel1 = client.channels.cache.find(channel1 => channel1.name === `ворота-1`)
      if (!channel1) return;
        if(message.content.includes(banwords))
        {
            bot.sendMessage({
               to: channel1
           })
        }
```

Comment: `message.content`  равен `undefined`. В этом проблема.

Comment: как сделать чтобы он не был равен undefined? Я обкопировал все docs по discord.js и результат один же.

Comment: Может, потому что сообщение пустое? Вы уверены, что есть свойство content такое?